# Where do I find the latest Google Docs API with the source code of the samples?

Tags: c#, google-docs, google-sheets, google-docs-api, google-sheets-api

I've been trying to use Google Spreadsheet API in C# by following  [these instructions](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/).

I downloaded the API from the official [Downloads](http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/downloads/list) page. However, there are two things wrong with it:

1. The API seems outdated, because I could not find the class `OAuth2Parameters` mentioned in the tutorial, only `OAuthParameters`.
2. The sample directory only contains executable files and no source code. I could really use the source code of the Spreadsheet.exe sample, as it fits my needs pretty well.

Answer (score 2):

You can grab the source code from the [project page](http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/) - I've just done that and built it with no problems. `OAuth2Parameters` is in the [`oauthparameters.cs`](http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/source/browse/trunk/clients/cs/src/core/oauthparameters.cs) file. I don't know if there's a binary release of the latest version of the libraries, I'm afraid.

(Note that I work for Google, but this post isn't written on behalf of Google - I haven't had much to do with the GData API, although I know someone who has, so if this answer doesn't help I may be able to get more information on Monday...)

Comment: @Ramhound: What's shocking about that?